# How might I define a character or string constant in C# for ASCII 127?

Tags: c#, string, constants, ascii, literals

How would one create a char or string constant containing the single character ASCII 127?

```
// Normal printing character - no problems
const char VPIPE = '|';
//error "The expression being assigned to 'DEL' must be constant"
const char DEL = new string(127, 1);
```

It would also be OK if the constants were strings instead of chars:

```
const string VPIPE = "|";
const string DEL = "???";
```

I know that ASCII 127 isn't something you can 'type' at the keyboard, but there has to be a way to create a string or char constant from it (or use a built-in one that I haven't found).

Comment: I believe you can initialize a constant like that in a constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
 const char s = ((char)127);
```

Comment: Thanks Exoas.  I got it just before seeing your response.  Thanks!

Comment: Oops.  Sorry for the late accept.  Thought I did that when I posted the comment...

Answer (score 12):

Personally I would use a "\u" escape sequence:

```
const char Delete = '\u007f';
```

I'm not keen on the "\x" escape sequence mentioned elsewhere - it isn't too bad in *character* literals (where multiple characters => compiler error), but it can be nasty for *string* literals:

```
// Tab the output
Console.WriteLine("\x9Good line");
Console.WriteLine("\x9Bad line");
```

Assuming you can see the bug here, how certain are you that you'd have avoided it when making "just a quick change"?

Given that I'm avoiding it for string literals, I think it makes sense to be consistent and just use "\u" everywhere that I want to escape a hex value.

Comment: Great answer, Jon, and I agree with (and I do see the bug between 9G and 9B.  I hate hidden bugs like that).  By the way, Holy #$^#!  Is that your real score?!?  Are you one of the founders of the site, or have you been here since like 1972?  lol.

Comment: @FlipScript: Don't forget that this is a Unicode world... the latter would actually use Unicode U+9BAD :) That's my real score, and I wasn't even in the betas. I do post "quite a lot" though :)

Answer (score 9):

`'\x7F'` will do it (and can also be embedded in a string if necessary).

Comment: See my answer for reasons to avoid the `\x` escape sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind.  I was a little too quick on the trigger on that one.

```
const char DEL = (char)127;
```